Getting error in building langchain vector database through chroma
Getting error in building langchain vector database through chroma. TypeError: Expected str, not <class 'pydantic.v1.types.SecretStr'>
def extract_text_and_build_index(pdf_path, index_name="attention_index"):
    pdf_loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_path)
    pages = pdf_loader.load_and_split()

    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=2000, chunk_overlap=200) 
    context = "\n\n".join(str(p.page_content) for p in pages)
    texts = text_splitter.split_text(context)

    embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding001",google_api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)
    vector_index = Chroma.from_texts(texts,embeddings).as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 5})`

That was my code in last line that is vector_index = Chroma.from_texts(texts,      embeddings).as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k":5}) it is showing error
TypeError: Expected str, not <class 'pydantic.v1.types.SecretStr'>
I tried changing API key the method but none of that worked. The API key is working fine there is no problem in API Key.
